# How to display data from psql database in my GUI made in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, desktop-application, psql

I have watched some tutorials how to make desktop app in `python` with `PSQL` database.

Now i know how to create GUI in `PyQt5` but I dont know how to connect data from `PSQL` database to my GUI.

For example I want to show data from table in `QTableWidget` but I cant find right answers on internet.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView
from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
def loadData(self):
     db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
     db.setHostName('localhost') 
     db.setPort(5432) 
     db.setDatabaseName('tbp_baza') 
     db.setUserName('postgres') 
     db.setPassword('admin123')
     dbliste = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers() 

     print(dbliste)

     if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Cannot open database",
                             "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"

                             "Click Cancel to exit.", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):

    super(mywindow, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    model =  QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
    model.setQuery("SELECT ime,prezime FROM korisnica")
    model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Ime")
    model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Prezime")
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

mydesign.py

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 350, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 256, 192))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
```

Comment: Use QTableView with QSqlQueryModel

Comment: Thanks, I added: 
model =  QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery("SELECT ime,prezime FROM korisnica")
model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Ime")
model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Prezime")
view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
view.setModel(model)
view.show()

How now connect it with table in GUI?

Comment: in your .ui change the QTableWidget to QTableView, then compile the .ui to .py, and then inside the class mywindow implements the logic. In conclusion, **do not use QTableWidget, you must use QTableView**

Comment: Now I think I changed all, but still no data showing.I will edit question with new code.

Comment: Have you opened the connection to the database? That is, you called the loadData function, why does loadData have a self parameter? Shows your progress as an issue to your question to know where the problem is

Comment: try with this code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/9162b73067d00a461778c2f00b112121

Comment: Thank you for the code, but still no data. I really dont get it.

Comment: share your mydesign.py and change `model =  QtSql.QSqlQueryModel() `to `model =  QtSql.QSqlQueryModel(self)`

Comment: I added in question mydesign.py

Comment: I have updated the gist code, try it again

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!! It works now.
I was thinking to give up on python and I always say that I will no longer work again in him but I always come back  :)
Sorry for your lost of your time.

Comment: Analyze the code, the logic and review your OOP concepts, also read [ask] and review the [tour] again so that next time you will not miss so much time for something so trivial